# Async Method in SignalR OnConnected()

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, signalr

I have the following:

```
    public override Task OnConnected() {
        HandleConnectionAsync(Context).Wait();
        return base.OnConnected();
    }
```

In following the guidance around "don't block a hub method", I'm trying to await my `HandleConnectionAsync` call, but if I use `async`, I end up with the following:

```
    public override async Task OnConnected() {
        await HandleConnectionAsync(Context);
        await base.OnConnected();
    }
```

But then I'm not returning anything.  What's the right way to do this?

Comment: The async version is the way to do this. Because the method is async and await is used the method will automatically return a Task.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But then I'm not returning anything. What's the right way to do this?

You don't need to return anything. `async Task` is the asynchronous equivalent of (synchronous) `void`. `Task` means there's no return value, so your code is already correct.

Put another way: `async` will construct the returned `Task`/`Task<T>` for you. So if your method does *not* have `async` (as in your first example), you need to return a task; but if your method *does* have `async` (as in your second example), then you don't.

Answer (score 0):

If you `await HandleConnectionAsync(Context);` the method won´t return until that part finishes.

If you don´t want to "block" the hub method, just remote the `Wait()` part:

```
public override Task OnConnected() 
{
    HandleConnectionAsync(Context);
    base.OnConnected();
}
```

That way the method will return immediately before `HandleConnectionAsync` finishes.